# Magento 2: What's best way to convert MySql to Magento

Tags: magento2, query, join, join-table

I've below MySql query, I would like to change use it in Magento format.

How can i do that ?

> **`SELECT customer_entity_varchar.value, customer_entity_text.value from customer_entity INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar ON customer_entity.entity_id=customer_entity_varchar.entity_id INNER JOIN customer_entity_text ON customer_entity.entity_id = customer_entity_text.entity_id`**

I've tried below but it only returns me. One table values not other ones.

```
 $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection();
    $select = $connection->select()
        ->from(
            ['customer_entity']
        )
        ->join('customer_entity_varchar', 'customer_entity.entity_id = customer_entity_varchar.entity_id')
        ->join('customer_entity_text', 'customer_entity.entity_id = customer_entity_text.entity_id');
    $selectnew = $connection->fetchAssoc($select);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($selectnew); exit;
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Check this, https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.db.select.html if you'll still have problem - update question with code you have and I'll help

Comment: You also can debug query using $select->__toString() it will return select statement

Comment: @StepanFurman, Above is my code. Pure SQL is working awsome, I need to convert it into Magento's format. Check my code and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: did you read the article by my link above? What did you try after that?

Comment: Check below:

`$items->getSelect()->join(array('l' => 'customer_entity_varchar'),
                    'l.entity_id = l.entity_id')
                    ->join(array('m' => 'customer_entity_text'),
                    'm.entity_id = l.entity_id')`

Comment: @StepanFurmanm, Its working out of the box, But both table i am joining both have same collumn with name **Value** that's causing issue. If you have solution for this most welcome. 

Is there any way so that i can change any of them collumn name from  value to my desire one ?

Comment: use column() and use aliases thet u set to tables.

Comment: Can you elaborate with example.

Comment: Add something like this ->columns('l.column_name');

Comment: @StepanFurman, You didn't get it, I am trying to say that, IS there is way. by which i can change collumn name while applying joins, Cause i have this in my `dataprovider` and this join returns me array with method `getData()` so if i dump these there will be two same keys so it will throw **Fatal Error** due to same Key, SO i need to change collumn name while i fetch data. Hope now you get it.

If you have M2 DB available you can execute this SQL you will get idea what i am saying.

Comment: Try this ->columns('l.column_name as alias');

Comment: working, what if i only need only value collumn from both table ?
`$items->getSelect()
                 ->join(array('l' => 'customer_entity_varchar'),
                    'l.entity_id = l.entity_id' )
                    ->join(array('m' => 'customer_entity_text'),
                    'm.entity_id = l.entity_id')
                    ->columns('l.value as profile')
                    ->columns('m.value as status');`

It returns me whole data. now i need to remove collumns expect i used status and profile. how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$items->getSelect()
->join(
    array('l' => 'customer_entity_varchar'), 
    'l.entity_id = l.entity_id', 
     array('profile' => 'l.value')
 )
->join(
    array('m' => 'customer_entity_text'),         
    'm.entity_id = l.entity_id', 
    array('status' => 'm.value')
 );
```

Comment: It will not work, Due to `Zend_Db_Select` will thorw undefined in Magento.

Comment: @Vivek I updated the answer above.

Comment: IF i use reset it will reset all collums including main table also, I only need to reset collumn of joined tables. How ?

Comment: @Vivek you can't reset particular table, see updated answer

Comment: @Stephan, Oh i See, No Worries. Still it works. Also now need to look for Zend too. :)